# Queue question in C++ and how Queue works in a simple program with examples

Tags: c++

Could you explain in detail what this means with examples? I want to know every line's meaning about how to write a proper queue program and I don't know how to learn C++ in a clear way. Should I copy and paste the whole program first without knowing why? Thank you so much!

I have problems specificly in : `front = (front + 1) % maxSize;`

```cpp
bool Queue::Dequeue(double & x) { 

    if (IsEmpty()) { 
        cout \<\< "Error: the queue is empty." \<\< endl; return false; 
    } else {
        // retrieve the front item 
        x= values[front];
        // move front 
        front = (front + 1) % maxSize; 
        // update counter 
        counter--; 
        return true; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: This lacks lots of context, so it's hard to answer without guessing. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list for some better resources for learning C++.

Comment: why not use standard `std::queue` or `std::deque`?

Comment: At a guess this is a circular buffered queue, because `% maxSize` ensures `front` is always less than `maxSize`

Comment: Stackoverflow is not an "introduction to data structures". Refer to a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). We cannot provide you with a line by line meaning of the statements.

Comment: Ok, why not experiment with it? Write a simple program that loops `front` from `0` to, say, `20`, and prints `(front + 1) % maxSize` for every value. You'll see a pattern very quickly.

Comment: you can use debbuger to check what is going on there

Answer (score 0):

I add comments for each line of code.

```cpp
bool Queue::Dequeue(double& x)
{
    if (IsEmpty()) // Judge whether the queue is empty.
    {
        cout << "Error: the queue is empty." << endl; // If the queus is empty, print a erro info.
        return false;  // Return false means dequeue fails
    }
    else
    {
        // retrieve the front item
        x = values[front];  // x represents current first elemen.
        // move front
        front = (front + 1) % maxSize;
        // update counter
        counter--;   // Counter means how many elements is in the queue, so when an element is dequeued, counter minus one.
        return true; // Dequeue successfully.
    }
}
```

Explanation for `front = (front + 1) % maxSize;`:

1. `front` is an index, it indicates the position of current front element.
2. When dequeue, his queue does not remove the element, it makes `front` plus one (or move `front` backwards). So the `front` will always represent the first element.
3. And `% maxSize` is to ensure that `front` will not exceed `maxSize`. When `front + 1` equals `maxSize`, `front` will become zero, it points to the first element. I believe that for this code, when pushing element into the queue and the number of elements reach the `maxSize`, it will rewrite first element. So it can keeps the number of elements always less and equal than `maxSize`.